# How can I serialize/store path object in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am kind of new to flutter and programming in general.

I am currently working on a drawing app where the user should be able to save the drawings and come back to them later on.
This means that I have to be able to store a path object locally.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path-class.html.
The problem I find is that I can't serialize the path object.

Here is a rejected PR where they wanted to implement a path iterator.
https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/5632

and here is an open issue about similar problem.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29125

I hope I explained my problem enough so that you understand my issue.

Do anyone have any idea of how I could serialize/store my path object?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by wrapping Path object in a new class that holds the Offsets separate.

It's not pretty but it works!

Comment: Hi, I'm currently facing the same problem as you. Do you save every single offset? That's what I've done but I've found that with big resolutions, it quickly leads to performance issues with the bucket fill functionality.